# How can I stop iTunes from asking me to sign in to iCloud Music Library?

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, ipad, icloud, music

I don't understand. iTunes keeps sending me this message:

[image: icloud-music-library-session-has-expired]

even though in System Preferences I am not signed in to iCloud music:

[image: icloud-system-preferences]

(There is, in fact, no option for iCloud Music to be found in iCloud System Preferences!)

Could it be that I am accessing my MacBook's iTunes music collection from an iPad? Does such sharing (under a LAN) constitute "signing in to iCloud Music"? If (hopefully) that's not the case, how do I stop the nagging message?

I *am* keeping "Find My Mac" and "Keychain" enabled in the iCloud settings. Is it necessary to abandon these two as well to avoid the ongoing sign-in request?

Comment: Are you using Apple Music? Find  My Mac and Keychain has nothing to do with this.