# How to avoid iTunes' "Do you want the application iTunes.app to accept incoming network connections?"?

Tags: itunes

The last few releases of iTunes 12.5.x.y ask, every time iTunes is launched:

[image: Do you want the application "iTunes.app" to accept incoming network connections?]

```
Do you want the application "iTunes.app" to accept incoming network connections?
```

Is there a way to select either answer as a default and avoid getting constantly asked that question?

Comment: You can probably set a default in System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Firewall and stop that from popping up?

Comment: @owlswipe   You're right. Exiting iTunes, turning the firewall off, and relaunching iTunes avoids triggering the dialog. The dialog comes back up when I turn the firewall back on while iTunes is running. In any case, turning the firewall off is a rather drastic solution!

Comment: There are no other settings in Firewall Preferences that could have an effect (without turning off firewall)?

Comment: @owlswipe thanks, that was it. I don't recall changing this setting. In any case, I wrote an answer.

Comment: @stuffe It's actually a 3-question questionnaire ;-). The other two questions are: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/271532/7985 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/222955/7985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**El Capitan**

Uninstalling and reinstalling iTunes is the only way I could solve this issue.

As [this](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/uninstall-itunes/) (battery-draining, maldesigned) page warns you, you can't just drag iTunes to the Trash. El Capitan will warn you that it's part of the OS. `Get Info`, clicking on the padlock, and giving everyone read+write permission will get over that.

The next step is to download it. Surprise: iTunes is not available on the App Store. But you can download a dmg just fine [here](https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/).

After 5 minutes of use I can confirm the message no longer appears.

I can also confirm that the music collection appears unharmed.

**Pre El Capitan**

Thanks to owlswipe's hint, the solution follows.

In System Preferences, under Security & Privacy

[image: system preferences]

Click "Firewall Options"

[image: incoming connections]

and allow incoming connections for iTunes.

It's not clear why "incoming connections" is an option for iTunes.

Comment: Happy to help! Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting then installing iTunes seems like a bizarre way to resolve this issue, but it's also the only solution I've found that actually works.

Comment: This page https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5262268?start=0&tstart=0   suggests that "some kind of permission or application signature" is the culprit. We're still waiting for someone to identify which file permission gets messed up. That would be a much lighter solution. (Not sure what an "application signature" might be.)

Answer (score -3):

You can use this command line in terminal

`sudo codesign --force --sign - <full path to application>`

It works for me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Why would the OP use this command?  What does it do?  Answers should be more than just 1 sentence.  See [answer] for important tips to follow when providing answers at this site.